# Can "multiply" be a noun?

Tags: nouns, mathematics

Can Multiply be used as noun, such as in "matrix multiply"? I heard of this from some Americans.

Or should it be "matrix multiplication" instead?

Comment: Anything can be a noun. This would have to be a very specific situation like “that matrix multiply (symbol) is fuzzy, we should reprint the page”. Your instinct seems good.

Comment: I don't think mathematicians are exactly renowned for their precise use of English (they think maths is the only "true" language anyway). But [as this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+matrix+multiplication%2Ca+matrix+multiply&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20matrix%20multiplication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20matrix%20multiply%3B%2Cc0), although there's a significant minority using the "wrong" form, the vast majority do get it right.

Comment: If someone said "matrix multiply" I would think they were talking about a particular algorithm (or implementation of one on a computer) for matrix multiplication.

Comment: why is that? @MarkS. Are you saying "matrix multiply" is correct for computer algorithms?

Comment: @Tim This is a guess, but I think it may come from the imperative form of the verb. If I want to "matrix multiply" two expressions in a program, I might call the function `MatrixMultiply` or something like that. At the very least, Mathematica has a function `NonCommutativeMultiply`, which may have given me the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with FumbleFingers. The experts from any domain have their own language and way of convincing the message. I'm a healthcare provider and while describing/discussing medical things among us, we generally overlook grammar because for us, that's trivial **in that case.**

I searched several dictionaries but could not find the word *multiply* as a **noun.** In my pro version of WordWeb (cannot give link here as it's not online) it says...

> Multiply as a *verb* and *adjective*. **Derived:** Noun: multiple, multiplication, multiplier.

I further tried to understand the term in mathematics as well. As you got it right, the correct [term is Matrix Multiplication.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) So, maybe, the experts use it in an informal way but the message is convinced.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be "multiplication".  "Multiply" is strictly a verb.

Answer (score 0):

*Multiply* can be a noun.  As in, "I performed one multiply followed by two adds."  In this case, a *multiply* refers to a mathematical operation.  It's often used this way in math and computer science.

It's similar to how we say, "I went for a run."    *run* is normally a verb but in this case it's a noun.